# Как обернуть значение ячейки Pandas в list

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датайфрейм:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0]})

df1
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Надо его привести к виду:

```
a    b
0  [0]  [0]
1  [0]  [0]
```

Никак не могу обернуть int в list. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: К сожалению, не получается так. TypeError: ("'int' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index a')

Comment: А зачем, можно узнать?

Comment: так точно получится :) df1.applymap(lambda x : [x])

Comment: Огромное спасибо